# How do i add a user-defined timer for a script?

Tags: timer, tcl, eggdrop

I'd like to add a command to my bot that will accept a user-defined amount of time for the trigger. the default for the trigger is 60 seconds. but I'd like users to be able to set this manually via the command.

example:

> [nick] @cmd 5s
>
> [bot] command initiating in 5 seconds

or

> [nick] @cmd 2m
>
> [bot] command initiating in 2 minutes

```
proc weed:pack {nick uhost hand chan text} {
if {[utimerexists delay] == ""} {
    putserv "PRIVMSG $chan \00303Pack your \00309bowls\00303! Chan-wide \00304Toke\00311-\00304out\00303 in\00308 1 \00303Minute!\003"
    global wchan
    set wchan $chan
    utimer 60 weed:pack:go
    utimer 60 delay
    }
}
```

and

```
proc weed:pack:go {} {
global wchan
putserv "PRIVMSG $wchan :\00303::\003045\00303:";
putserv "PRIVMSG $wchan :\00303::\003044\00303:";
putserv "PRIVMSG $wchan :\00303::\003043\00303:";
putserv "PRIVMSG $wchan :\00303::\003042\00303:";
putserv "PRIVMSG $wchan :\00303::\003041\00303:";
putserv "PRIVMSG $wchan :\00303::\00311\002SYNCRONIZED!\002 \00304FIRE THEM BOWLS UP!!!"; return
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's mostly about understanding `utimer`. That command takes two arguments, a count of the number of seconds to wait, and a command (*including arguments* if relevant) to execute when the timer fires.

All you need to do is to figure out how to parse the user-supplied time. We can use `scan` for that.

```
scan $text "%d%1s" count type
```

It's best to check the result of that to see if you've succeeded; on success, there'll be a 2 returned (for two fields). Now that you've picked things apart, you have to convert it into a count of seconds:

```
if {[scan $text "%d%1s" count type] != 2} {
    # Do an error message; don't just silently fail! Don't know eggdrop enough to do that properly
    return
}
switch -- $type {
    "s" { set delay $count }
    "m" { set delay [expr {$count * 60}] }
    "h" { set delay [expr {$count * 60 * 60}] }
    default {
        # Again, you ought to send a complaining message to the user here
        return
    }
}
utimer $delay weed:pack:go
```

Stick that all inside your `proc` with whatever other bits you need and you should be good to go. If you've got several places that need that parse, you can even convert that code to its own procedure; that's what I'd go for really, as “parse a duration description” is a good candidate for that sort of thing.